# Locating specific scripts functions that are applied on any given DOM element in the browser using Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for the specific scripts functions that are applied on any given DOM element in the browser. I am using the Chrome Developer tools for this. I am able to locate the style rules in a very organised way on the right. I am looking for something similar to get specific js functions or code which are affecting a given DOM.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but in the Elements tab, you can right-click on an element and add a breakpoint ("Break on..." menu item).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node